# Missing CSS property in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I found out that the "background" property is missing in Firefox but in Chrome isn't.

At my [site](http://www.acromix.net16.net), in Chrome:
[image: image1]

in Firefox:
[image: image2]

Why and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`-webkit-` is a [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Vendor prefixes are used as long as a feature isn't totally specified. `-webkit-` is the one used by Chrome and Safari.

For Firefox, you need `-moz-`, or rather nothing in this specific case as the linear gradient is now supported without prefix on all major browsers.

Comment: oh yeah, why do i always forget this